# Error in C# code

Tags: c#, sql

```
public void ExecStoredProc(string strprocName, SqlConnection sqlConnect, List<string> Paramvalues)
{
    if (ConnectToDB() == true)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strprocName, sqlConnect);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = strprocName;

        SqlParameter parameters = new SqlParameter();
        parameters.Value = Paramvalues;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

This code is giving an error when I am passing the name of the procedure `login` which has two parameters,`user` and `pwd`. Though I am using the list to add parameters but it not not passed to the SP. Showing error in the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything useful with the `parameters` variable that you declared. There is no relation between the command and the parameters.

Comment: @Darin Yes that is the point.Can give the line that connects the command and the parameters.

Comment: What exactly is the error, in your code add a try catch block to catch the exception and post the error message. Also, you need to be adding the parameters collection to the command object before executing the command object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are declaring a new SqlParameter object you are not actually associating that object with cmd. Adding the below should help:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add sqlparamerter into `cmd.Parameters`
`cmd.Parameters(new SqlParameter("Uid",value));`
and no need to write `CommandText`.

Comment: Parameters is a collection, not a method, so it would be 'cmd.Parameters.Add()'. You are correct about `CommandText` being redundant though.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter { ... }).Value = Paramvalues;
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact that you're not adding the parameter back to the command, you also have a list of strings as your parameter value. Your naming leads me to believe that each item in the list is a parameter. The way your code is at the moment, you're just creating one parameter (with no name).

You want something like this (except we don't know the parameter names):

```
foreach(string value in ParamValues)
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(/*ParamName*/, value);
}
```

If this is not the case and you want to pass the list of strings as a value for a single parameter then this question is more complicated and you need to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Model = ObjectLibrary.Model;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;


public class Base
{
    protected ArrayList Parameter = new ArrayList();


    public DataTable FetchData(string spName)
    {
       //if you want to get it form app config else just hard code here
       string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
       return ConnectToSql(connectionString, spName);
    }
    protected void ClearParameter()
    {
        Parameter.Clear();
    }
    protected void AddParameter(string parameterName, object value)
    {
       Parameter.Add(new SqlParameter(parameterName,value));
    }

    private DataTable ConnectToSql(string connection, string spName)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn;
        conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connection;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(spName, conn);
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(Parameter.ToArray());
            SqlDataAdapter dataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dataAdaptor.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

  }
```

You can use this class